What do people call an equation that describes a relationship between a functional and one or more of its functional derivatives?
"Functional differential equation" seems to already be used for something different (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation). I'm talking about something like the Schwinger-Dyson equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation):
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta \varphi(x)}\left[-i \frac{\delta}{\delta J} \right] Z[J] + J(x)Z[J]=0$$
Is there a common term in the literature for such an equation? I ask because I'm wanting to find out if people have developed methods for computing Lie symmetries (or something analogous) of such equations like they have for ODEs/PDEs (see, for example, Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations by Peter J. Olver).

I guess you could say it is a form of differential equation.

Seems to be in the constellation of "variational equations".  Possibly relevant: 1, 2, and 3.
